# Suitability of SAML for use case

Tags: authentication, single-sign-on

A user logs into our portal - site 1;

We want them to be able to click through to other sites 2 and 3 within our eco-system without having to further login - so no popup box to verify they have permission to access this site.

It would be further ideal if the user could visit site 2 first, and if no session is present, have the popup to login - and have this login session then work if the user visited site 1 or 3.

So login once, verified everywhere.

My question is, can this be done with SAML - probably using SimpleSAML for both ends.

The other option I am considering is pubcookie, which I am pretty sure will work but is not as well supported or modern. All sites will be sub-domains of an .com domain.

Thanks all..